# Our own php Side login but not go to header('Location: home.php');

Tags: php

Our php Side full work in my localserver (Xamp-apach-5.5.6)
but hosting side no work(apach-5.2.17)
Please help me.

```
public function login($username,$password)
    {
        session_start();
        if($username==!NULL AND $password==!NULL)
        {
            global $pdo;
            $password=md5($password);
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee_list WHERE username='$username' AND userpass='$password'");
            $query->execute();
            $row=$query->rowCount();
            if($row==0)
                {
                $this->massage->loginmass("<span class='text-danger'>YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD NO MATCH.</span>");
                }
            else
                {
                    $result = $query->fetch();
                    if($result['active_enactive']=="Active")
                    {
                         $_SESSION['mafizusernamerahman'] = $result['username'];
                         $_SESSION['mafizuserpassrahman'] =$result['userpass'];
                         $_SESSION['mafizaccess_permissionrahman'] = $result['access_permission'];
                         $_SESSION['mafizactive_enactiverahman'] = $result['active_enactive'];
                         $_SESSION['mafiznamerahman'] = $result['name'];
                         $_SESSION['mafizemployment_idrahman'] = $result['employment_id'];
                         $_SESSION['mafizfather_namerahman'] = $result['father_name'];
                         $_SESSION['developer'] = "Mafizur";
                        if($_SESSION['mafizaccess_permissionrahman']=="Admin")
                            header("location:all-employee.php");
                        elseif($_SESSION['mafizaccess_permissionrahman']=="User")
                        {
                            if (empty($result['defaltpass'])) {
                                header("location:user-profile.php");
                            }
                            else
                                header("location:defaltchange-password.php");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        $this->massage->loginmass("<span class='text-danger'>YOUR ACCOUNT SUSPEND.</span>");


                }
        }
        else
            $this->massage->loginmass("<span class='text-danger'>PLEASE FILL UP YOURUSER NAME AND PASSWORD.</span>");

    }
```

Comment: Format your questions in the future; this is unreadable as is. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @Mafiz, use 4 spaces as a prefix to format your code nicely.

Comment: Also you have not explained what is not working.

Comment: You are using prepared statements incorrectly, you are open to SQL injections with this code. Do you have anything in your error log? We can only guess at your current issue.

Comment: Explain your problems exactly ? Do you have the problem like its running on local server and stopped working after migrating to new hosting place ? If so the check the settings for your live server

Answer (score -1):

You need to be careful while using relative URLs in `Location` redirects.

So, it will be better if you print absolute URLs in the headers instead of relative URLs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location